# NodeJs 14.x version : "Error: incorrect header check", " at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror]

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, zlib

I have following code to convert csv t json using zlib in node js got the error

```
  const originalText = await s3.getObject({
                    Bucket: event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name,
                    Key: event.Records[0].s3.object.key
             }).createReadStream().pipe(zlib.createGunzip());
```

Error:

```
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "incorrect header check",
    "code": "Z_DATA_ERROR",
    "errno": -3,
    "stack": [
        "Error: incorrect header check",
        "    at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:182:17)"
    ]
}
```

Any suggestion would be really appreciable.

My header is

```
PMonth,CMonth,IID,PID,UsID,Name,Code,BillEntity,CType,Cost,Flag
2021-01,2021-02,664938733,3.2457411,8.3716111,CloudWatch Events,AWSEvents,AWS, Usage,1.041514,N
```

Comment: That would be because your compressed data has the wrong header. Likely a zlib header where your code is looking for a gzip header.

Comment: But I saw header is right.. Please find the edited post

Comment: "BillMonth" is not a zlib header.